# Problems with deploy in Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, war

Well, this is my directory structure:

[image]

Inside folder META-INF (/src/main/java) i have "persistence.xml". The problem is: when I deploy this project to WAR Project, this WAR don't contains persistence.xml and log4j.properties.

Comment: did you set any exclusion tag?

Comment: what did you mean with "exclusion tag" ?

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your resource files (eg. `persistence.xml`) in

```
src/main/resources
```

Comment: When i do it, occurr the following error: "No persistent unit with name 'odontonewPU' found...", in other words: Can't possible find persistence.xml in /src/main/resources;

Comment: `persistence.xml` should be in `src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`

Comment: Doesn't Maven copy the files under resources in WEB-INF/classes? Genuinely asking.

Comment: @alexgrimaldi Yes, when you're using `<packaging>war</packaging>`. In JEE6 persistence unit can be defined in a war.

Comment: I put the "log4j.properties" and "persistence.xml" (/META-INF/) inside /src/main/resources/ and WAR file have the files normally. But when i try to start my server the error is: "Error listenerStart"

Comment: But inside my "classes" folder don't have persistence.xml and log4j.properties, and i think this is the problem. The Deploy (Maven) don't transfer the META-INF to Classes folder.

Comment: Run `mvn package` and check if `target/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml` exists. (Assuming `src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml` exists)

Comment: @BoristheSpider Nope, `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml` it the proper location. See here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnbrj/index.html

Comment: @rzymek, my persistence.xml is located on "src/main/webapp/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml". But in deploy the "target/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml" don't exists.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41118/discussion-between-rzymek-and-user2776409)